# Parallelizing fortran 2008 `do concurrent` systematically, possibly with openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

The fortran 2008 `do concurrent` construct is a do loop that tells the compiler that no iteration affect any other. It can thus be parallelized safely.

A valid example:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  integer, dimension(10) :: array
  do concurrent( i= 1: 10)
    array(i) = i
  end do
end program main
```

where iterations can be done *in any order*. You can read more about it [here](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1701-N1750/N1729.pdf&ei=LScHUMCxCoio0QXo06jCDQ&usg=AFQjCNHsTHiC6wQOuEOBhc0BCLHbA2tVhA&sig2=oDMd622TdgwtwmFHYWja_g).

To my knowledge, gfortran does not automatically parallelize these `do concurrent` loops, while I remember a gfortran-diffusion-list mail about doing it ([here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-09/msg00016.html)). It justs transform them to classical `do` loops.

**My question**: Do you know a way to *systematically* parallelize `do concurrent` loops? For instance with a *systematic* openmp syntax?

Comment: If you are still onto it - don't use `FORALL` with `workshare`. See may updated answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not that easy to do it automatically. The `DO CONCURRENT` construct has a *forall-header* which means that it could accept multiple loops, index variables definition and a mask. Basically, you need to replace:

```
DO CONCURRENT([<type-spec> :: ]<forall-triplet-spec 1>, <forall-triplet-spec 2>, ...[, <scalar-mask-expression>])
  <block>
END DO
```

with:

```
[BLOCK
    <type-spec> :: <indexes>]

!$omp parallel do
DO <forall-triplet-spec 1>
  DO <forall-triplet-spec 2>
    ...
    [IF (<scalar-mask-expression>) THEN]
      <block>
    [END IF]
    ...
  END DO
END DO
!$omp end parallel do

[END BLOCK]
```

(things in square brackets are optional, based on the presence of the corresponding parts in the *forall-header*)

Note that this would not be as effective as parallelising one big loop with `<iters 1>*<iters 2>*...` independent iterations which is what `DO CONCURRENT` is expected to do. Note also that *forall-header* permits a *type-spec* that allows one to define loop indexes inside the header and you will need to surround the whole thing in `BLOCK ... END BLOCK` construct to preserve the semantics. You would also need to check if *scalar-mask-expr* exists at the end of the *forall-header* and if it does you should also put that `IF ... END IF` inside the innermost loop.

If you only have array assignments inside the body of the `DO CONCURRENT` you would could also transform it into `FORALL` and use the `workshare` OpenMP directive. It would be much easier than the above.

```
DO CONCURRENT <forall-header>
  <block>
END DO
```

would become:

```
!$omp parallel workshare
FORALL <forall-header>
  <block>
END FORALL
!$omp end parallel workshare
```

Given all the above, the only *systematic* way that I can think about is to *systematically* go through your source code, searching for `DO CONCURRENT` and *systematically* replacing it with one of the above transformed constructs based on the content of the *forall-header* and the loop body.

**Edit:** Usage of OpenMP `workshare` directive is currently discouraged. It turns out that at least Intel Fortran Compiler and GCC serialise `FORALL` statements and constructs inside OpenMP `workshare` directives by surrounding them with OpenMP `single` directive during compilation which brings no speedup whatsoever. Other compilers might implement it differently but it's better to avoid its usage if portable performance is to be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Do you have a source to read from about this discouraged behavior?

Comment: With GCC you can look at the [source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_7-branch/gcc/fortran/). Some constructs are parallelised, e.g. array assignment, but `FORALL` is not among them. With other compilers you can look at the assembly output.

Comment: I should also add that compiler vendors are actually solving exactly the same problem that you are trying to solve :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean "a way to systematically parallelize do concurrent loops". However, to simply parallelise an ordinary `do` loop with OpenMP you could just use something like:

```
!$omp parallel private (i)
!$omp do
do i = 1,10
    array(i) = i
end do
!$omp end do
!$omp end parallel
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Sorry for the vague "systematically". As an example, could I _grep_ or _awk_ the `do concurrent`; XX; `end do` everywhere in the code, and replace it (_sed_ or _awk_, for instance) with always the same openmp syntax. Should not be occurrence specific (but the looping variable of course).
Your answer may help in this way, but is it always the correct syntax for all kinds of stuff in between `do concurrent` and `end do`?

Comment: As far as I know this should be sufficient, given the restrictions on what can go into a `do concurrent` construct - hopefully someone more knowledgeable can chime in here. The one concern I have about what you are trying to do is that when using a `do concurrent` construct the compiler will check to see if what you are doing in the construct is allowed by the Fortran standard but this won't happen if you sed/awk etc. So if you make a mistake this simple translation may not be appropriate and could lead to unexpected results which may be hard to track down.